# C# GroupBy to produce flat header detail list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list and I want to make it a header / detail list. For example, the item is:

Item {GroupName, ItemName, Price}

```
Fruit, Apple, 10
Fruit, Orange, 15
Fruit, Pear, 20
Drink, Soda, 5
Drink, Coke, 15
```

The grouped data structure:
GroupedItem {GroupName, Min(Price), Max(Price)}

The final header / detail list combines GroupedItem and Item:

```
Fruit, 10, 20
Fruit, Apple, 10
Fruit, Orange, 15
Fruit, Pear, 20
Drink, 5, 15
Drink, Soda, 5
Drink, Coke, 15
```

In c#, I think I can use a GroupBy to produce a group hierarchy and then use 2 ForEach to flatten the structure (simply add them all to a new list by iterating all header and detail). Is it possible to use LinQ to produce the combined list (List< Object>) directly?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: It should be up to UI element not data in programming List doesn't have header / details concept ... also it's not clear how you would put `Item` and `GroupedItem` to the same `List<T>` without using  `List<dynamic>` or `List<object>`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JgAwwu

Answer (score 1):

How are you supposed to combine `GroupedItem` and `Item` objects in the same collection? What type do you want the collection to be?

The `GroupedItem` class should have a property to hold the items in the group:

```
GroupedItem[] = groupedItems
    .GroupBy(g => g.GroupName)
    .Select(g => new GroupedItem { GroupName = g.Key, Min = g.Min(x => x.Price), Max = g.Max(x => x.Price), Items = g.ToArray() })
    .SelectMany(g => g.Items)
    .ToArray();
```

You can use a nested loop to present each group however you want in the presentation layer.

Comment: The combined list will be list<object>. As mentioned in my question, I know that I can produce a nested hierarchy but I need a flat one. Thanks.

Comment: @Nick: So how are you planning to use the `List<object>`?